# Android Emulator in M1 with Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I'm using the Android Emulator Preview for the M1 MacBook Air, everything works almost fine, except that when a try to use Firebase, I get this error

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2259): Google Play Store is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2259): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
```

I can't find how to install Google Play Store on the M1 Emulator.

Any idea how??

Comment: You've loaded the wrong system image.

Comment: how can I load the correct image?? I'm completely lost...